# Windows virtual wifi hostednetwork - set max number of clients?

Tags: windows, wifi, access-point, netsh

I'm building an app that has functionality that creates on the fly a new virtual wifi utilizing the Windows 7 / 2008 features. I can create it just fine, but am looking how to limit the maximum number of connections. By running a "netsh wlan show hostednetwork" command to view my settings - it shows (by default 100), but it HAS to be somewhere in the registry right? - I can't see any settings available for this either at the command line or using the api - so I have to assume it's stored in the reg. I see vwifi and hostednetwork registry keys in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\ - Wlansvc\parameters\hostednetworksettings, etc... but can't find any reference to add a "MaxClients" value (or similar) - would like to limit it to only one connection. Has anyone seen any references to this, or know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an API. `WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_CONNECTION_SETTINGS` structure.

Please refer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd439499%28VS.85%29.aspx